# When should I use RESTful?

Tags: web-services, rest

I don't exactly know what RESTFUL is. Sure I know it's a mapping of a URL to a resource. But how's that different from an ajax call to a codeigniter URL which echos some JSON?

My application will have subscriptions with states/options, is there any reason I should be using a RESTful setup rather than just some ajax calls when a user switches some of the options for their subscriptions?

Comment: rest is all about transfer of state! if you're implying that you just want to be able to invoke some method on the server for switching options on a subscription, you're more referring to a RPC style of programming.

Comment: Easy. RESTful means stateless. All the information needed to do the "operation" is sent in that one single command. The server can come up and go down between calls and a RESTful operation doesn't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not necessarily use "pure" REST. If your requirements drive you towards an HTTP-based service returning JSON, then great. But that doesn't imply that you need other aspects of the REST architectural style. You may not need:

1. An architecture based on resources, in the sense they're defined by the HTTP protocol
2. A URL structure that maps to resources
3. You may not want the return result from one request to provide a set of URLs which indicate "where to go" for related requests.

REST is an architectural style, but it can also become a "religion". Be certain that whatever you do is driven by the requirements you need to fulfill, and not based on "ideology".